# How to fix an error with not permitted database file?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have a java application with spring boot, hibernate and postgres database. And sometimes I've got this error when do a regular select operation:

```
ERROR: could not open file "base/21125/1239" Operation not permitted. Where: parallel worker
```

Where should I look up a solution? May it be some problem with transaction isolation? Or it's somewhere on operation system level with it's file permissions?

Comment: This error is most certainly emitted by postgres, so you'll want to look into itslogs instead of the application level. File permissions? Disk corruption?

Comment: Do you use SELinux?

Answer (score 1):

There is something that is interfering with PostgreSQL.

The typical culprit in that case is a virus scanner.

Configure virus scanners and similar nuisances to exclude the PostgreSQL data directory.